# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment hides behind keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want to show my **BottomSheetDIalogFragment** on top of the screen when keyboard open. I search in web and found some solutions but no one can not solve my problem. I add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to my **AndroidMnifest.xml**. My dialog style is:

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
</style>
```

in java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme);
}
```

and

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;

            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
```

and

```
if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {

        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }
```

in **onCreateView** method. But my problem was not solved. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my style to this and my problem solved:

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```